# For two subgroups $H_1, H_2$, how can I show $H_1 \cup H_2$ is subgroup $\iff$ $H_1 \subseteq H_2$ or $H_2 \subseteq H_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to shot that for two subgroups $H_1, H_2$, $H_1 \cup H_2$ is a subgroup iff $H_1 \subseteq H_2$ or $H_2 \subseteq H_1$

The implication $\impliedby$ follows easily, as (without loss of generality) if $H_1 \subseteq H_2$ then $H_1 \cup H_2 = H_2$ which is a subgroup by assumption.

It's easy to give counterexamples for the case where (wolg) $H_1 \not \subseteq H_2$, e.g. $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm struggling with giving a rigorous proof for either $(\lnot \impliedby \lnot)$ or $(\implies)$

I'm really stuck, and would appreciate any hints.

Comment: If neither $H_i$ is a subset of the other, take an $a\in H_1-H_2$ and $b\in H_2-H_1$, and show that $ab$ can't be in $H_1\cup H_2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If neither is subgroup contained in the other, then they each contain an element that's not contained in the other. Consider the product of those two elements.

Comment: I see why these pairs of elements must be the cornerstone of the proof, but how can I show that the product of at least one of these pairs **must** be outside $H_1 \cup H_2$?

Comment: @RubenKruepper (It's the product of _any_ such pair, which is why it's enough to assume that there is "at least" one.) Consider what $x\in H_1\cup H_2$ means: that $x\in H_1$ or $x\in H_2$. Disprove both, and you're done. (Or disprove one and claim that the other one follows analogously. It's not like the two proofs are going to be  different in any significant way.)

Comment: @RubenKruepper Consider how you would prove that the sum of a rational number and an irrational number cannot be rational. This is basically the same.

Comment: Yes, but it **is** irrational, which is exactly what's confusing me. I see why it "possibly isn't" in either $H_1$ or $H_2$, but not why it "can't possibly" be in $H_1$ or $H_2$.

Comment: I've opened a separate question with the special case where $H_1$ has only one element, as this seems to be a more fundamental result.

Comment: @Arthur... What's the line of thought through which you got this idea? Thank you.. the hint worked!!

Comment: @adityabhatt This is a standard exercise in both group theory and in linear algebra (where you have subspaces instead of subgroups). I got this idea because I've seen it many times before. One of those times was the first time, and I don't think I solved it on my own back then. But since that time, I have known how to prove this result.

Answer (score 0):

If $H_1\cup H_2$ is a group, and $H_1$ is not contained in $H_2$, then there exists $g\in H_1$ with $g\notin H_2$. Now, what happens to $gh$ for each $h\in H_2$? It has to be in $H_1\cup H_2$, because this is supposed to be a group. Is it in $H_2$?

And what does that tell you about all these $h$?